# Datatable empty cells using inertia and vue3

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, datatables

I am using Laravel Inertia with Vue3. I used the package https://datatables.net/blog/2022-06-22-vue for the data tables. The problem is I passed the data from the controller to vue as props but it wont render correctly. I got empty cells but it has the correct data count.

[image]

I got this alert when I go to the component

```
DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_17 - 
Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. 
For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4
```

Here is my datatable component code

```
          <DataTable :data="tenants" class="display">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Database</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
          </DataTable>
```

Here is my vue devtools props details

[image]

I just found a way to partially work by doing

```
          <DataTable class="display">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Database</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr v-for="tenant in tenants" :key="tenant.id">
                <td>{{ tenant.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ tenant.tenancy_db_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ tenant.email }}</td>
                <td>
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-info">Update</button>
                  &emsp;
                  <button @click="deleteTenant(tenant.id)" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Delete</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </DataTable>
```

But the problem is when I add or delete on the table I need to switch to other component and go back in order for the table to update.

[image]

Code from controller

```
    public function index(){
        $tenants = Tenant::all()->toArray();

        return Inertia::render('Tenants/Index',[
            'tenants' => $tenants
        ]);
    }
```

Then in my component

```
defineProps({
  tenants: Array,
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If the data structure is an array of objects then according to the [documentation](https://datatables.net/blog/2022-06-22-vue), we need to use the `columns` to populate the object properties.
2. [Working with Reactive Data](https://datatables.net/blog/2022-06-22-vue) is also mentioned in the documentation where the package will automatically reflect the changes made to the data.

So, if you can try the following, it might help-

```
<DataTable
    class="display"
    :columns="columns"
    :data="tenants"
    :options="{ select: true }"
    ref="table"
/>
```

where columns data according to tenants array could be-

```
const columns = [
  { data: 'id' },
  { data: 'tenancy_db_name' },
  { data: 'email' },
];
```

Comment: Thanks for this one It worked. Can I ask another question? What if I need a custom column I will add it on the `column` array right? It works but when I add a function like `{data: null, className: 'btn btn-primary', defaultContent: '<button @click=delete(data.id)>Delete</button>'.` It says data is not defined. Even I replace it with props is still not defined. And the `@click` doesnt work.

Comment: I write it here for test https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-uthzbk?file=src%2Fmain.js,src%2FApp.vue

Comment: `defaultContent` is used to display the static content, so the button will not get executed. I think you should use the 'render' function. Something like this- `{data: 'data', render: function (data, type, row, meta) {return '<button onclick="test(data.id)">Delete</button>'; },},`

To read more that how can you use render, see here- https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render

Comment: Also, On [this link](https://datatables.net/blog/2022-06-22-vue) scroll down to the `DataTables API` which is about updating and deleting methods of row.  You will also find the [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/datatables-net-vue3-reactive?file=src%2FApp.vue) there.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. I tried it but still got `test is not defined` even i put it in `methods` or `setup`

Comment: I used Datatable only for API columns, I didn't try for the custom columns. However, your question's error is resolved now. the custom column is another point that I'll try and let you know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250387/discussion-between-neha-soni-and-draw134).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you cannot loop the `Reactive` array based on the props you posted. Also based on this [link](https://datatables.net/blog/2022-06-22-vue) it needs to be some kind of normal array.
You might need to convert your props from reactive to a normal array.

```
const data = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
];
```

Comment: It's not completely true, working with an array of objects is also mentioned in the documentation.